# emails to gsuite addresses bounce

Tags: civimail, mailing

I am having trouble sending email to addresses in our own GSuite domain.  They bounce with a "syntax" error, and the addressee gets flagged as ON HOLD.

Using CiviCRM with Wordpress, current versions.

Any ideas, friends?

Answer (score 2):

Sending emails that appear to come from within the organization but are from an outside server is a common scammer's tactic, and Google is much quicker to not deliver these emails.  To get delivery, you'll need to configure an [SPF record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en).  This will improve all-around deliverability - but is 100% required for delivering to your own domain when using GSuite.

Comment: That was very helpful.  We do have SPF configured, but perhaps not quite correctly.  We failed the Google checkmx test.  I am looking into it now.  Thanks!